# Magento Paypal Express and Standard Difference in Code - empty Basket

Tags: magento

When using paypal on magento there are two clear choices, standard and express.

Its quite confusing the differences actually between them, but one of the main differences is that paypal standard completes the order straight away at the point of redirecting to paypal whereas express doesnt.

This essentially means that a users basket gets cleared using paypal standard at the point of transfer to paypal  and if they click back they will not have basket.

At which exact point in the code is this occurring?

I can see the two payment methods in magento:

```
app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Express.php
```

and

```
app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Standard.php
```

but i cannot see where magento allows express to keep the order ongoing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual flow between Express and Standard is different...

**PayPal Express**

User gets redirected to PayPal directly after the payment method has been chosen (and obviously before the order has been completed).  They return to the site to complete the order after authorising payment with PayPal.

**PayPal Standard**

User goes through entire checkout process and completes the order on site.  They then get redirected to PayPal to sort out payment.  They do not need to come back to the site to complete the order as it has already been completed before redirecting to PayPal.  This is why you see the empty basket if you return to the site regardless of whether you pay at PayPal or not - **the quote has already been converted to an order.**

So in this sense PayPal express is essentially checkout method and PayPal standard is a payment method.

---

With regards to the exact place in code that this all happens...

**PayPal Express**

Uses the [getCheckoutRedirectUrl()](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express.php#L428) method which gets called in the [savePayment() action of  Mage_Checkout_OnepageController](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php#L426) - so you get redirected before the order is completed as described above.

**PayPal Standard**

Uses the [getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php#L108) which gets called in the [saveOrder() method of Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php#L797)

*Please see the links for exact code points that everything happens.*

Answer (score -1):

Partial answer based on a quick check of the code, maybe this will at least point you in the right direction.  Let me know what you find and I'll try and do some additional digging and provide more detail.

```
// Mage_Paypal_StandardController
public function redirectAction()
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $session->setPaypalStandardQuoteId($session->getQuoteId());
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypal/standard_redirect')->toHtml());
    $session->unsQuoteId();
    $session->unsRedirectUrl();
}
```

Notice that the quote_id is unset on the checkout/session.  That just might do it.

And in the Express controller, I don't see any place where the `quote_id` gets unset:

```
// Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract
public function placeOrderAction()
{
    ...
}
```